# Facebook Graph api 2.2 - App scoped user id uniqueness

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I have a database full of user Ids as primary keys prior to the upgrade to app scoped Ids.

After upgrade , could a new app scoped id ever match a previous user id ?

The only confirmation I can see on the FB developer documents is that the accounts that have approved apps prior upgrade would continue to work with user Ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they can't. All ids are unique

Comment: Appreciate the answer. But, Is there an official facebook guide/document that mentions  this?

Comment: well, since wizkid works at facebook, you can consider it official ;) - and why would a user id (app scoped or not) NOT be unique?

Comment: It makes sense for it to be unique .. There is a vague mention on the dev docs but nothing specific .I did not want to base my work on assumption :)